# How to overlay one list on the second using Stack in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a page that displays 2 lists. By design, I need to make one list cover the second list a little, that is, I need to overlay one list on the second. I tried to do it through Stack but I ran into a problem that the bottom list does not scroll then, tell me how can I overlay one list on the second as shown in the screenshot below?

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(child: Text('Test'));
              }),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.brown[700]),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 5,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return SizedBox(child: Text('Test'));
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Comment: you want to show one list on the other one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your front list in `Positioned` and set the `top` as much as you want like this:

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 200,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blueGrey),
            child: ListView.builder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100),// <----important part
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return SizedBox(child: Text('Test1'));
                }),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.brown[700]),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SizedBox(child: Text('Test2'));
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

[image]

Comment: And I will scroll the list 2 upper and lower? I just tried this and only the top list scrolled, and the bottom one didn't.

Comment: As you can see in my gif, both list scroll. not that , pass bottom padding as much as the height of front list to list one.